# jQuery not works on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, onclick

I am using Rails and I am trying to create a bookmark icon in ajax.
The code works, the problem is on the first click the request is sent but the image doesn't change, for the next clicks the behavior is OK (request sent and image change).

My view:

```
<%= link_to favorite_company_job_path(@job, matching_id: candidate.id), method: :post, remote: true do %>
  <span class="favorite">
    <% if candidate.favorite %>
      <img src="<%= asset_url "favorite-activated.png" %>" alt="favorito" class="img-40" id="favorite_activated_<%= candidate.id %>">
    <% else %>
      <img src="<%= asset_url "favorite.png"%>" alt="favorito" class="img-40" id="favorite_<%= candidate.id %>">
    <% end %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

My file favorite.js.erb

```
$('#favorite_<%= @matching.id %>').on({
  'click': function(){
    $('#favorite_<%= @matching.id %>').attr('src','<%= asset_url "favorite-activated.png" %>');
    $('#favorite_<%= @matching.id %>').attr('id','favorite_activated_<%= @matching.id %>');
  }
});

$('#favorite_activated_<%= @matching.id %>').on({
  'click': function(){
    $('#favorite_activated_<%= @matching.id %>').attr('src','<%= asset_url "favorite.png" %>');
    $('#favorite_activated_<%= @matching.id %>').attr('id','favorite_<%= @matching.id %>');
  }
});
```

My controller:

```
def favorite
    @matching = @job.matchings.find(params[:matching_id]) 
    if @matching.favorite
      @matching.favorite = false
    else
      @matching.favorite = true
    end
    @matching.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to company_job_path(@job) }
      format.js  # <-- will render `app/views/company/jobs/favorite.js.erb`
    end
  end
```

Any idea?

Comment: I don't your request code. Can you paste your full JS?

Comment: @AntonTkachov I added my controller code, but for the JS it's all I have in my favorite.js.erb for now.

Comment: First of all you don't need `$(document).ready(function() {` in your js response. Try to delete it and just respond with Pure JS code. Try it and answer whether it works now?

Comment: @AntonTkachov I removed it, but the problem persist

Comment: Can you please update your question accordingly, so it will be easier for other to be up-to-date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see from your code right now, that in your response you just setup listeners for click, while what you actually need to do is just to launch your code. You don't need listeners, because you've already setup them in rails itself:

```
<%= link_to favorite_company_job_path(@job, matching_id: candidate.id), method: :post, remote: true do %>
```

I think that changing your `favorite.js.erb` and setup just a part of code that you expect to be a callback:

```
$('#favorite_<%= @matching.id %>').attr('src','<%= asset_url "favorite-activated.png" %>');
$('#favorite_<%= @matching.id %>').attr('id','favorite_activated_<%= @matching.id %>');

$('#favorite_activated_<%= @matching.id %>').attr('src','<%= asset_url "favorite.png" %>');
$('#favorite_activated_<%= @matching.id %>').attr('id','favorite_<%= @matching.id %>');
```

should work for you. Hope this helps

Comment: @Etienne Got your review, double checked everything from the docs and rejected the edit. jQuery handles all condition on its own end. You will never get anything like 'method called for nil/undefined', because jQuery selector will always return you jQuery collection, that can accept any kind of actions. In case of optimization it's also unneeded, because it's client side script and you have minor JS (no bottlenecks possible). But keeping your code smaller and simpler is always a great pro

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
`$('#id').on('click', function(){});`

Use 
`$(document).on('click', '#id', function(){});`

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Same problem, the behavior didn't change